# Javadoc warning: no @param for type when using Lombok @Builder

Tags: java, javadoc, lombok

when generating javadoc from sources (delomboked) I receive following warnings for the builder classes generated by the Lombok's `@Builder`

```
[ERROR] Error while creating javadoc report: 
Exit code: 1 - /path/to/project/ProjectData.java:85: warning: no @param for type
        public ProjectData.ProjectDataBuilder type(final ProjectType type) {
```

Here is a part of delomboked class causing warning:

```java
/**
 * @return {@code this}.
 */
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
public ProjectData.ProjectDataBuilder type(final ProjectType type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
}
```

And here is what is assumed a proper, no warning-producing javadoc - with `@param` present

```java
/**
 * @param type some meaningful description
 * @return {@code this}.
 */
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
public ProjectData.ProjectDataBuilder type(final ProjectType type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
}
```

**Is there a way to make de-lombok generate these as well? There are a lot of such warning in my project and they kind of clouds all the relevant actual errors.**

Comment: What is the JavaDoc on your field declaration of `type`?

Comment: Arguably, your "no warning-producing javadoc" should have produced a warning. There is absolutely no value in that line of "code" You see the name of the parameter. Well, that's already in the code. I wish that that type of javadoc, or similarly `@param type the type` would be flagged.

Comment: @JanRieke none. But as you mentioned it - I've added some and its being copied both to the field in delomboked class as well as its put over the builder method for that field. Problem is that its copied 1:1 so its just a description for the method, and `@param` is "not allowed" over fields in the original,lomboked file.

Comment: @RoelSpilker yes, you are absolutely right, I've edited the question. Of course I want to have some meaningful message there, not just "the type" or "type" :D

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Lombok versions¹, delombok will copy the `@param` placed in the field Javadoc to the corresponding builder method.

This is an extension of the existing [`@Getter/@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) feature, which already moved `@param`/`@return` to the corresponding setter/getter.

You can also *optionally* put fully custom documentation using `-- SETTER --`/`-- GETTER --` (the `@param` and `@return` tags must then be in the corresponding section in that case):

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LombokJavadoc {
    /**
     * my nice field
     *
     * -- SETTER --
     * sets the something
     *
     * @param something a nice value
     * -- GETTER --
     * access for something
     *
     * @return a nice value
     */
    private String something;
}
```

Generates:

```
public class LombokJavadoc {
    /**
     * my nice field
     */
    private String something;


    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
    public static class LombokJavadocBuilder {
        […]

        /**
         * sets the something
         *
         * @param something a nice value
         * @return {@code this}.
         */
        @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
        public LombokJavadoc.LombokJavadocBuilder something(final String something) {
            this.something = something;
            return this;
        }
    }

    […]

    /**
     * access for something
     *
     * @return a nice value
     */
    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
    public String getSomething() {
        return this.something;
    }

    /**
     * sets the something
     *
     * @param something a nice value
     */
    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
    public void setSomething(final String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
    
    […]
}
```

¹ This appears to actually have been implemented in PR [#2008](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/pull/2008), which was part of [v1.18.6](https://projectlombok.org/changelog)